# using floats to store large numbers

Tags: c++, precision

I'm using `floats` to represent a position in my game:

```
struct Position
{
    float x;
    float y;
};
```

I'm wondering if this is the best choice and what the consequences will be as the position values continue to grow larger. I took some time to brush up on how floats are stored and realized that I am a little confused.

(I'm using Microsoft Visual C++ compiler.)

In `float.h`, `FLT_MAX` is defined as follows:

```
#define FLT_MAX         3.402823466e+38F        /* max value */
```

which is `340282346600000000000000000000000000000`.

That value is much greater than `UINT_MAX` which is defined as:

```
#define UINT_MAX        0xffffffff
```

and corresponds to the value `4294967295`.

Based on this, it seems like a `float` would be a good choice to store a very large number like a position. Even though `FLT_MAX` is very large, I'm wondering how the precision issues will come into play.

Based on my understanding, a `float` uses 1 bit to store the sign, 8 bits to store the exponent, and 23 bits to store the mantissa (a leading 1 is assumed):

```
    S EEEEEEEE MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
```

That means `FLT_MAX` might look like:

```
    0 11111111 11111111111111111111111
```

which would be the equivalent of:

```
1.11111111111111111111111 x 2^128
```

or

```
111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Even knowing this, I have trouble visualizing the loss of precision and I'm getting confused thinking about what will happen as the values continue to increase.

Is there any easier way to think about this? Are `floats` or `doubles` generally used to store very large numbers over something like an `unsigned int`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way of thinking about the precision of a float, is to consider that they have roughly 5 digits of accuracy. So if your units are meters, and you have something 1km away, thats 1000m - attempting to deal with that object at a resolution of 10cm (0.1m) or less may be problematic.

The usual approach in a game would be to use floats, but to divide the world up such that positions are relative to local co-ordinate systems (for example, divide the world into a grid, and for each grid square have a translation value). Everything will have enough precision until it gets transformed relative to the camera for rendering, at which point the imprecision for far away things is not a problem.

As an example, imagine a game set in the solar system. If the origin of your co-ordinate system is in the heart of the sun, then co-ordinates on the surface of planets will be impossible to represent accurately in a float. However if you instead have a co-ordinate system relative to the planet's surface, which in turn is relative to the center of the planet, and then you know where the planet is relative to the sun, you can operate on things in a local space with accuracy, and then transform into whatever space you want for rendering.

Answer (score 0):

No, they're not.

Let's say your position needs to increase by 10 cm for a certain frame since the game object moved.

Assuming a game world scaled in meters, this is 0.10. But if your `float` value is large enough it won't be able to represent a difference of 0.10 any more, and your attempt to increase the value will simply fail.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to store a value greater than 16.7m with a fractional part?  Then float will be too small.

[This series by Bruce Dawson may help](http://randomascii.wordpress.com/category/floating-point/).

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to handle very large numbers, then consider using an [arbitrary-precision arithmetic library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic). You will have to profile your code because these libraries are slower than the arithmetics of built-in types.

It is possible that you do not really need very large coordinate values. For example, you could wrap around the edges of your world, and use [modulo arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_arithmetic) for handling positions.

Comment: This is a reasonable general solution, but for a game, where performance is critical, it's better to work with/around the imprecision. So long as you understand it, it can be dealt with.